# Adding toggle on a triple nested UL Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The first nest of the UL seems to be working fine, but when I clicked on the second nest of UL the problem I encounter is it's closing the first nest. I want the second nest of UL to show. To be exact I want to show the child element of My Job Listings.

```
<ul id="hb_sidebarmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dashboard<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">View Profile</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">Edit Profile</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">Account Settings</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>My Clients</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Pending Applications</div></a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Messages<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">My Job Listings<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></a>
                <ul class="submenu_1">
                    <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">Web Developer</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">Content Writer</div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">Inbox</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name">Sent Items</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="hb_menu_name"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>Headquarters</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#hb_sidebarmenu li ul").hide();
    $("#hb_sidebarmenu li").click(function(){
        $(this).find('.submenu').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing your jQuery function from `find()` to `children()` it will target only the direct child, thus only opening the submenu directly under the `li` that you have clicked.

Your jQuery will look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#hb_sidebarmenu li ul").hide();
    $("#hb_sidebarmenu li").click(function(){
        $(this).children('.submenu').toggle();
    });
});
```

Looking at your code, I would also suggest changing your targeting element to your `a` tag instead.

If you wanted to achieve this, you can adjust your jQuery to use the `next()` function instead like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#hb_sidebarmenu li ul").hide();
    $("#hb_sidebarmenu li a").click(function(e){
        if ($(this).next().is('ul')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next().toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Frits, I tried the second solution.

Everything is working fine on second nest, but clicking on the second nest which is "My Job Listing" the UL is still not showing.

Comment: Upon debugging clicking the seoncd nest is not entering the function $("#hb_sidebarmenu > li > a").click(function(e) {});

I think because the container of LI is on the upper part and the LI > a is below?

Comment: Cool, my mistake. I've adjusted the second code block to instead check if there is a submenu next to the a link, and then open it in that case :)

Comment: Wow @Frits. The final code block is working great. I just need to figure out why the animation is not applying. I think it's because it's display:none to display:block. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @BellaCarandang you're very welcome :) if you want to animate it, you can change `toggle()` to `toggleFade()` or `slideToggle()` instead :) cheers!

Comment: Hi @Fritz. I have figured out that adding #hb_sidebarmenu .submenu {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

transistion to the ul will conflict to the slidetoggle. It's working fine now. Thank you :)

Comment: HI @Fritz. Just an additional tweak. How can I add a background color on the opened li? I tried something

$(this).next().toggle(function() {
$(this).parent().css("background-color","pink");
});

But the pink remains.

Comment: This would probably be better as a seperate question, but imo the best way to achieve this would be to `toggleClass('active-menu')` and then in your CSS assign `.active-menu {background-color:pink;}` as a rule. [__Like this__](https://jsfiddle.net/zyu9my9n/). If you want to improve on this function even more, work out what you want to do, and ask a new question with your attempts showing :) You're welcome to ping me to come and have a look at your new question when you do :) Don't forget to search through SO as chances are high of it being answered previously :)

Comment: Got this @fritz. Thank you :) Noted on what to do the next time I will ask. Cya